# How do we understand ideal generation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was doing polynomial thing in abstract algebra, and I am confused with the assumption that (2,x) being an ideal generated by two terms while proving Z[x] is not a principal ideal ring.. How exactly we can say (2,x) is an ideal generated by two terms x and 2 as until now I have read only about ideal being generated with just 1 element.

Comment: *How can we say that $(x,2)$ is an ideal – Mukul Yadav 12 mins ago* The notation $(x,2)$ means *by definition* the ideal generated by $x$ and $2$. Written another way, it is equal to $x\Bbb Z[x]+2\Bbb Z [x]$, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal generated by a finite number of elements $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ in a ring $A$ is somehow like the span of a finite number of elements in a vector space. Explicitly, it is the set of linear combinations $a_ix_1+a_2x_2+\dotsm+a_nx_n$ with coefficients $a_1, a_2,\dots,a_n\in A$.

It is easy to check this set is an ideal. This ideal is usually denoted $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. In a P. I. D., this ideal is principal, and any generator is called a `g. c. d.` of $\;x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n$.

Comment: So we are defining an ideal using 2 elements in the problem of Z[x] and saying that it cannot be generated by any single element in Z[x]. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes. This proves $\mathbf Z[x]$ is not principal. Actually, $A[x]$ is a P. I. D.  if and only if $A$ is a field.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a ring and $S\subset A$ a subset, then the ideal generated by $S$ is the smallest ideal of $A$ containing $S$. Or put differently, it is the intersection of all ideals of $A$ that contain $S$.

Comment: How can we say that (x,2) is an ideal

Comment: I am unable to understand how (x,2) is an ideal

Comment: We can take any no. Of elements and the product of those with all other elements is an ideal??? Doubt